# Paypal Recurring Billing via sandbox account

Tags: php, paypal

I have successfully set up an account with which I can create a business account and personal account but now i want to integrate recurring billing of paypal in my website and i think paypal merge sanbox and live account in one so i'm little bit confused regarding recurring billing. If any body have recurring billing procedure/tutorial so please let me know.

really appreciate your quick and soft response.

Comment: If you can provide the email address for your test sandbox seller account I can check to see if recurring billing is enabled on it.

Comment: Here is my complete paypal info. Is anything missing please let me know.
 sandbox.paypal.com

tariq_ali786@hotmail.com
android@

Buyer

tsdreamer_ts@hotmail.com
android@

seller

tariq.webstar@gmail.com
android@

Comment: I show that your sandbox account with the email address of tsdreamer is enabled for Website Payments Pro and recurring payments.  You should be able to test with this account.

Comment: Dear PP_MTS_Chad,
Do you have any code of recurring billing of paypal ?

Comment: You can find some sample code at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples#recurringpayments as well as our SDK's are available at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index#expresscheckoutnew